# Angular 2 compiler version

Tags: typescript, npm

After install latest version of TypeScript with:

```
npm uninstall -g typescript
```

I can see latest version installed: typescript@2.1.5.
But when I try to get the tsc compiler latest version I obtain:

```
tsc -v Version 1.0.3.0
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Ok, probably it was a Visual Studio installation. I found in path variables path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0.

Comment: I couls also rename the folder  to disable path entry, but first solution is cleaner. Thanks